# Understanding a sentence with a conjunctive form of an adjective, ため, 中, and ということになる

Tags: meaning, translation

I understand this might be a bad question, but I'm trying to understand the following part of a sentence from the [following question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/98321/what-does-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97-signify-here) (or the following [Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E7%B3%BB)):

> 投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く、 その言葉は 「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指すため「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったのが「なろう系」ということになる

And it seems like I more or less understand the parts but don't understand what it means as a whole. Well, I'm certainly missing something.

It ends with ということになる, as such I guess it should follow the pattern "A conjunction B ということになる," which [means](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/98321/what-does-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97-signify-here/98323#98323) that from A follows B. In this case:

> A - 投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く、 その言葉は 「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指す
>
> conjunction - ため
>
> B - 「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったのが「なろう系」ということになる

I could probably split it at 多く, since this is a [conjunctive form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/%e7%84%a1%e3%81%84-and-%e7%84%a1%e3%81%8f-difference/13615#comment29468_13614) (連用形) of 多い and can [act as](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/%e7%84%a1%e3%81%84-and-%e7%84%a1%e3%81%8f-difference/13615#13615) a conjunction. But ため itself supposedly links cause and effect, as such it seems like a better candidate.

A has 2 clauses:

> C - 投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く
>
> D - その言葉は 「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指す

My understanding of what it means:

> C - 投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く
>
> even (も) in case (で) of commercial works (商業作品) [published in places] other than (以外) contribution websites (投稿サイト) [there are] many (多く) works (作品) that utilized (利用した) the framework (枠組み) similar (よう) to the one mentioned above (上記)
>
> and
>
> D - その言葉は 「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指す
>
> that word (その言葉) indicates (指す) scope (範囲) wider (広い) than (よりも) that of Mary Sue novel (「なろう系」)

From C and D follows:

> B - 「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったのが「なろう系」ということになる
>
> in case (で) of being (中) reincarnating to another world (「異世界転生もの」) thing (の) that holded (持った) big (大き) influence (勢力) is Mary Sue novel (「なろう系」)

I'm not sure which word they refer to (その言葉), what it all means, which mistakes I made and what I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look at the wiki page, it would seem その言葉 is referring to the various *expressions:* 「なろう」、「なろう小説」、「異世界転生系」、「異世界転生もの」

Answer (score 3):

You asked about その言葉, but it actually refers to something that was in the same sentence but was excluded from the excerpt. Here's the original sentence in Wikipedia:

> なろう系と異世界ものはほぼ同じ意味となっており、「なろう」、「なろう小説」、「異世界転生系」、「異世界転生もの」とも呼ばれるが、杉本穂高は投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く、**その言葉**は「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指すため「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったのが「なろう系」ということになるとし、広い意味で異世界へ行くオンライン小説作品をなろう系だとすると往時の作品群がインターネットに掲載されていたら該当するため、カルロ・ゼンはそれらと異なる点として、異世界へ行って帰ってくる往時のようなものより、なろう系は異世界へ行ったままなことを挙げている。

First, I must point out that this sentence is not only unnecessarily long but also poorly structured. It's hard for me to follow who said what. It might be important to be able to infer the intended message from a disorganized sentence like this, but this is not a suitable sentence for someone like you who wants to analyze text logically.

Still, as long as you know some basic knowledge about these genre names, what その言葉 refers to is clear. Here, it refers to the genre "異世界(転生)系/もの". I made an edit to the original text. If you can interpret the following easily, you can forget the original text as something poorly written.

> 現代では「なろう系」と「異世界もの」はほぼ同じ意味となっており、「なろう」、「なろう小説」、「異世界転生系」、「異世界転生もの」などと総称されている。一方で杉本穂高は、投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多いため、「異世界もの」は「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指すものだ、とする。彼によれば、「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったものが「なろう系」ということになる。
>
> 広い意味で異世界へ行くオンライン小説作品をなろう系だと定義するならば、そのジャンルは作品の内容ではなく発表方法で定義されるものになる。往時の作品群も、もしインターネットに掲載されていたら「なろう系」に該当することになってしまうだろう。そのためカルロ・ゼンは、両者が異なる点として、往時の作品群では登場人物が異世界へ行って帰ってくることが多いが、なろう系は異世界へ行ったままであることを挙げている。

Comment: 両者が異なる点として means "as a point where two sides (往時の作品群 and なろう系) differ"?

Comment: @JohnDavies Yes.

Answer (score 2):

The passage seems to adapt [the following passage](https://animeanime.jp/article/2021/07/24/62773.html) (link in the Wikipedia article)

> なろう系は、しばしば「異世界転生もの」とも呼ばれますが、この投稿サイト以外の商業小説や漫画でも同様の物語を採用したものが数多く生み出されている状況です。そのため、「異世界転生もの」は、「なろう系」より大きな枠組みを指すもので、その「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を占めるのが「なろう系」と理解するとわかりやすいでしょう

So その言葉 refers to 異世界転生もの (in contrast with なろう系).

The passage in question means "D(=異世界転生もの > なろう系) because of C, and as such B(=なろう系 is a popular genre within 異世界転生もの)".